# Pantheon Integration of Google Drive

Tags: pantheon-files, files, photos

Are there any plans to integrate an optional connection to Google Drive in the Pantheon file manager? I remember that when I was with Gnome 3 it was as if Google Drive was yet another hard drive or connected device on my computer. Is this possible in elementary OS? Or is it something you guys are looking into?

Comment: If you can create a gvfs mount or fuse mount to Google Drive then it should appear in Pantheon Files.  I believe this can be done at the command line in Loki although I haven't tried myself.  There are no plans to produce a specific google drive plugin for Files but it is intended to produce a more general online account solution at some point.

Comment: That's what I assumed, but I thought I should ask. I will look into your suggestion and see what I can do.

Answer (score 5):

google-drive-ocamlfuse is what you want. 
It integrates Google Drive as a removable drive into Pantheon Files and/or Nautilus. It is free too.

Find detailled info on how to set it up (and to automatically mount at startup) here: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/mount-google-drive-in-linux-with-google.html

Only issues I have is that it feels kinda slow (I have a 120 Mbit/s connection) loading thumbnails and ...
EDIT: Seldom disconnects after suspend have stopped and I can't reproduce the issue anymore.